# Enable to print whole web page using window.print() javascript function

Tags: javascript, .net

I am using window.print() JavaScript function for printing a web page. But it is not printing full page.

Comment: What part of the page is printed then? A possible cause could be CSS rules defined for printing.

Comment: Calling window.print has the same effect as printing without JS intervention. Presumably you have some CSS that is limited what gets printed (possibly accidentally via, for example, absolute positioning). It isn't possible to say exactly what without a lot more information though.

Comment: Another possible cause could be that printing of background colours and images is switched off in your browser. Tools > Internet Options > Advanced to turn it on in IE.

You'll need to specify a bit more detail before you get a solution though, methinks.

Comment: It is printing 70 % of page. Even when I tried to print a page from stackoverflow.com it is printing 70 % of page.

Comment: Are you saying that any time you try to print from your browser, no matter what the page, then the bottom third is cut off? This sounds like there is a problem with your system and the question should be addressed to SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Review the whole code, also the included css rules. Perheps it help you.. http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/Sample/

Comment: 30% Right part of page is not displaying for my application. Able to print out some pages. For example it is not displaying 30% of stackoverflow.com

Comment: **Displaying** ? Do you mean "rendering when printed" or does this also apply to the screen? **your application** ? Do you mean a web browser you are writing? Do you mean a web application that pulls content from third party websites (if so how?) ? Something else?

Comment: Application is working fine. When I run my application it is displaying full page but when I try to print it out it is printing 70% of page. This application is asp.net application.

Comment: I am using IE6 for printing page

Answer (score -1):

Give a chance to the follow JQuery plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/print

digging the link above you get this sample

http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/Sample/

Comment: (a) That is a tag, not a single plugin. (b) Throwing a big pile of generic JavaScript at something that should "just work" isn't the right approach (and is unlikely to work).

Comment: Why do not you dig deep inside the documentation ? I'm sure you will find something that fits to you. You do not need to use the thing, get the main idea, that all man.

Comment: I refer you back to point 'b'. Throwing JavaScript at this is not the way forwards.

Comment: all right! The soluition is there, but it is a not so BIG PILE of generic JavaScript.. and it works fine. thats all, is a solution, if @john wants to use or not, he decides.

Comment: The solution doesn't appear to be there. It is a big pile of generic JS. If it works fine - please demonstrate it working on the page that isn't currently printing as expected.

Comment: @David take a look at this link http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/Sample/  and then click on Popup button

Comment: That still isn't going to cause the whole page to print when only part of it does at present. You have to identify the problem and fix that.